# How to make a text label to fit in rectangle in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I have a label containing string "Hello" i want this label to fit in a rectangle. How can i make the rectangle size same as the size of label? Here is my code.

```
UiLabel*label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(40,60,50,30);
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
label.text = @"Hello";
[label sizeToFit]// it make the size of label fit with text size
```

Here is my rectangle in which i want to fit my label

```
UIView*rectangle = [UIView alloc]init];
rectangle.frame = CGRectMake(40,60,50,30);
```

Comment: no need of this `[label sizeToFit]`, and use `rectangle.frame = label.frame`

Comment: – Anbu.Karthik i want the label width with text width thats why i use [label sizeToFit] got my point?

Comment: you want o adjust the label width based on text correct

Comment: – Anbu.Karthik  i want o adjust the label width based on text and then fit the label into rectangle

Comment: o yes i got the point thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `boundingRectWithSize`. It can be used to calculate the size the string will take.

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello";

//or an font you want
UIFont *font =  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];

//This is to ensure word wrap is used and the maximum width and height that label size can be calculated is inside screen bounds
CGRect rect = CGRectIntegral([hello boundingRectWithSize:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font} context:nil]);

//create Label    
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[tempLabel setText:hello];
[tempLabel setFont:font];
[tempLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[tempLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.view addSubview:tempLabel];
```